# What is the best option to LOAD/UNLOAD schemas from a Redshift cluster to another cluster on another region on a schedule?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-redshift

I have two Redshift clusters on two different regions, one is production and the other is development. I need to export multiple schemas from production cluster to dev cluster on a weekly basis. So I am using the Prod UNLOAD --> S3 --> LOAD Dev approach to do this.

Currently I am using the query below which will return a table of query commands I need to run.

```
select 'unload (''select * from '||n.nspname||'.'||c.relname||''') to ''s3://my-redshift-data/'||c.relname||'_''
iam_role ''arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:role/my-redshift-role'' ;' as sql
from pg_class c  
left join pg_namespace n on c.relnamespace=n.oid
where n.nspname in ('schema1','schema2')and relkind = 'r'
```

The results returned look something like below:

> unload ('select * from schema1.table1') to 's3://my-redshift-data/table1_' iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:role/my-redshift-role';
>
> unload ('select * from schema2.table2') to 's3://my-redshift-data/table2_' iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:role/my-redshift-role';

Just some additional information, I have a Kubernetes cluster on the same vpc as my Redshift cluster, running apps that are connecting to Redshift cluster. I also have a Gitlab server that have gitlab runners that are connected to Kubernetes cluster using Gitlab agent. There are a few ways I can think of to do this:

1. Using Gitlab scheduled pipeline and run the UNLOAD/LOAD script using Redshift Data API
2. Using Kubernetes batch job to run UNLOAD/LOAD script using Redshift Data API
3. Using AWS Lambda and write a python script (something new to me), and schedule it using Event Bridge?

I would appreciate any suggestion because I can't decide what is the best way to approach.

Comment: Hi Kent. I suspect the downvote is because you're asking for a recommendation or opinion; this isn't well accepted due to (mis-)interpretation of [site guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). You have a few ways you know this could work; determining which is best depends on your situation.

Comment: @KirkBroadhurst thank you for pointing out why my question was downvoted. I have little to no knowledge in python and lambda and I don't want to spend too much time in learning it and turning out it doesn't achieve what I want, as the whole thing is waiting to be deployed to production.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever building anything new it's helpful to think about the time / cost / quality tradeoff. How much time do you have? How much time do you want to spend supporting it in the future? Will you have time to improve it later if necessary? Will someone else be able to pick it up to improve it? etc.

If you're looking to get this set up with as little effort as possible, and worry about the future when it happens, it's likely that a Gitlab pipeline & Redshift Data API will do the job. It is quite literally just a few calls to that API.

- you need an IAM role for your Gitlab runner to authenticate to the API, which you likely already have. Obviously check that the role has the correct access.
- you can store the database credentials as Gitlab variables as a fast/simple option, or leverage some more secure secret store if necessary / critical
- remember that the IAM role needs to access both the "source" (prod) and "target" (dev) clusters; if they are in different accounts this is more setup.